# If I click outside of PhpStorm my git changes disappear in the editor

Tags: git, phpstorm

Every time when I click outside of my IDE, my git changes disappear in PhpStorm.

Here is a video to get a better understanding:
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wlCn.jpg**

I don't know if this is a problem with git or PhpStorm itself, I've tried to delete my `.idea` directory, but that didn't helped. Other projects don't have this problem.

Comment: Looks like it is committing automatically. Nothing is being lost.

Comment: Cannot speak about Git status changes ... but you may disable this option to disable autosave when app looses focus: `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Save files when switching to a different application or a built-in terminal`

Comment: This isn't a well-known problem: unfortunately I can't tell why this is happening or advise an immediate workaround. I would suggest to contact support via Help | Contact Support or create a report at JetBrains tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue to have this closely inspected.